# Group by more than 3 columns

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm trying to group the list by 3 levels and somehow I couldn't get it working. From the forums, I found this link: http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2015/05/group-by-more-than-2-columns-sharepoint.html and I'm following it to the letter.

But somehow I'm getting a blank page when I open the page on SharePoint site.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Any suggestions from anyone?

Comment: Viewed 19 times and no suggestions? Everyone facing the same issue?